# Deploy/Publish multiple lambda serverless project in one go

Tags: asp.net-core, aws-lambda, serverless

I have VS solution file and multiple lambda project in it. To deploy/publish my lambda to AWS, I have to go individual project and need to right click and then need to click on "Publish to AWS Lambda". I'm having 10+ lambda project in my solution and need to do this exercise repeatedly.

Is there any solution to deploy all this lambda function on single click?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the [AWS PowerShell tools](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/index.html) to create a quick script to publish your functions in one run

These two functions [Publish](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/index.html) and [Update](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/items/Update-LMFunctionCode.html) should suffice.

Here is a sample script PowerShell script to publish a single lambda

```
$zipFile = "E:\my-awesome-function\release.zip"
$zipFileItem = Get-Item -Path $zipFile
$fileStream = $zipFileItem.OpenRead()
$memoryStream = New-Object System.IO.MemoryStream
$fileStream.CopyTo($memoryStream)   

//Check if function exists
$cmdOutput = Get-LMFunction -FunctionName my-awesome-function;

try{
    if($?) {
        "Function exists update the code"               
        Update-LMFunctionCode -FunctionName my-awesome-function -ZipFile $memoryStream -Publish 1

    } else {
        "Publish new function"           
        Publish-LMFunction -FunctionName my-awesome-function -FunctionZip $zipFilePath -Handler exports.handler -Role arn:aws:iam::0000000:role/my-extract -Region us-east-1 --Runtime python3.6
    }
}
finally {
    $fileStream.Close()
}
```